# Sequelize Include multiple model to single parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

can i create a multiple include (with different structure) for single parent using sequelize ?

```
Order.findAll({
    include:[
        {
            model: Hotel,
            as:'product_detail',
        },
        {
            model: Flight,
            as:'product_detail',
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Can you show model and association definitions?